# Retrieve data from a SQL Server Database and set it into TextBox in NET.Core MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MVC NET.Core proyect where a teacher is expected to fill some inputs in order to submit a student report. To make things easier, I want to call the database where all the info of students are located, and whenever the teacher fills the input field for StudentId, my program makes a call to the database and autofill other inputs like the name, last name, birth date, and so on based on this StudentId.

I was following [this solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zgu_PF0tFf0) but it's not for NET.Core MVC, I have tried by making an ActionResult() but honestly, I don't know if this is the best way to do so.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SearchStudent() {
        try {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("---Connection String---");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DBO.STUDENTS WHERE ID = @ID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(form["idEstudiante"])); //I want to pass the id the user type in an output field in view
            
            // I stopped here since I was unable to make a code for changing the outputs in view based on the information I retrieve from the database.


        } catch(Exception) { 
        
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Solicitud
{
    /*#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#*/
    /*| Identificadores de la Tabla                                                                                                         */
    /*#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#*/
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DisplayName("Numero")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /*#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#*/
    /*| Informacion de la Tabla                                                                                                             */
    /*#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#*/

    //  I. Información de la solicitud

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La fecha en que se realiza la solicitud es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Fecha en  la que se realiza la solicitud")]
    public DateTime? FechaRealiza { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la persona solicitante es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Nombre de la persona solicitante")]
    public String? NombrePersonaSolicitante { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El puesto que desempeña la persona solicitante es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Puesto que desempeña la persona solicitante")]
    public String? PuestoDesenpenna { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Otro anote es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Otro anote")]
    public String? OtroAnote { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El identificacion del estudiante es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Nombre del estudiante")]
    public String? identificacion { get; set; } // ID of student

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre del estudiante es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Nombre del estudiante")]
    public String? Nombre { get; set; } // Name of student

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El apellido del estudiante es obligatorio")]
    [DisplayName("Apellido del estudiante")]
    public String? Apellido { get; set; } // Last name of student
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
<div>
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div>
            <h3>I. Información de la solicitud</h3>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FechaRealiza" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="date" asp-for="FechaRealiza" class="form-control fecha-actual"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="FechaRealiza" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NombrePersonaSolicitante" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="NombrePersonaSolicitante" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="NombrePersonaSolicitante" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PuestoDesenpenna" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="PuestoDesenpenna" class="form-control" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OtroAnote" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OtroAnote" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OtroAnote" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Identificacion" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Identificacion" class="form-control" />
             <!--Here I want to add the event to autofill the fields-->
            <span asp-validation-for="Identificacion" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Nombre" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Nombre" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Apellido" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Apellido" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Apellido" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
 </form>
```

I would like to have an idea on how to retrieve data and set it on outputs. Thanks!

Comment: I would first walk through this tutorial on using EF Core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli This will give you a strongly typed model, you can then use that model in your MVC page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever the teacher fills the input field for StudentId, my program
> makes a call to the database and autofill other inputs like the name,
> last name, birth date, and so on based on this StudentId.I have tried
> by making an ActionResult() but honestly, I don't know if this is the
> best way to do so.

Well, its easy to implemenet but you should know couple of stuff to achieve that. For instance, you should know [javascript on change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0),  [Sql queries for load data by search key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries) and better if you know [entity framework query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0) additionally. In next steps, I will implemeent and explain you why would require that.

Let's assume you have below model:

```
public class Solicitud
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [DisplayName("Numero")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El identificacion del estudiante es obligatorio")]
        [DisplayName("Nombre del estudiante")]
        public String? Identificacion { get; set; } // ID of student

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre del estudiante es obligatorio")]
        [DisplayName("Nombre del estudiante")]
        public String? Nombre { get; set; } // Name of student

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El apellido del estudiante es obligatorio")]
        [DisplayName("Apellido del estudiante")]
        public String? Apellido { get; set; } // Last name of student
    }
```

**Note:** I have narrowed down your origial model into above one so that. We will insert `Identificacion` number and based on that we will search and load other two property based on inserted `Identificacion`. You can load 1000 of property following the same.

View:

```
@model YourProjectName.ModelFoler.Solicitud

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div>
                <h3>I. Información de la solicitud</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Identificacion" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Identificacion" id="Identificacion" class="form-control" />
                <!--Here I want to add the event to autofill the fields-->
                <span asp-validation-for="Identificacion" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nombre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nombre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Apellido" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Apellido" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Apellido" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Identificacion").change(function () {
                alert("Click");
                var identificacion = $("#Identificacion").val()
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:5094/AutoFill/SearchStudent',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { identificacion: identificacion },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#Nombre").val(response.nombre);
                        $("#Apellido").val(response.apellido);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error!');
                    }
                });


            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Here,  `$("#Identificacion").change(function ()` is very important. when we will be inserting any `student Identificacion` number then your  `SearchStudent(string identificacion)` controller action will be invocked and execute our search query. Therfore, javascript `onChange` event is crucial here because whatever, will be inserted sooner it need to call. Let's move forward.

Controller:

```
public class AutoFillController : Controller
    {
       
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SearchStudent(string identificacion)
        {

            Solicitud solicitud = new Solicitud();

            string cs = "YourSQLServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            var command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT Id,Identificacion, Nombre, Apellido FROM Solicitud WHERE Identificacion = '{0}'", identificacion);
           

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                solicitud.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                solicitud.Identificacion = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                solicitud.Nombre = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                solicitud.Apellido = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
            }



            con.Close();
            return Ok(solicitud);



        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

**Best Way:**

Well, reagrding the best way, I would say, its depends. For your scenario, first implement using above way which you are currently following because, at the begining its better to know how SQL works. In addition, it can be handled even easier way [using Entity framework.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

**Entity Famework Implementation:**

Well, if you prefer, entity framework, in that scenario you should aware of below changes.

Dbcontext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
       
         public DbSet<Solicitud> Solicituds { get; set; }
     

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
                  modelBuilder.Entity<Solicitud>().ToTable("Solicitud");

        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public class AutoFillController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;



        public AutoFillController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SearchStudent(string identificacion)
        {
            var sutdent = _context.Solicituds.Where(s => s.Identificacion == identificacion).DefaultIfEmpty();
            return Ok(sutdent);
        }
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**Note:** Everything in the view will remains same. Furthermore, I would recommend you to check our official document for more details.

1. [Asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0)
2. [TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/lesson-1-creating-database-objects?view=sql-server-ver16#read-data-from-a-table)
3. [Javascript Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/beginners-series-to-javascript/?languages=javascript)

Comment: Thanks! This worked very well, at first I didn't understand why `nombre` in `response.nombre` wasn't capitalized like all other "nombre" variables in the code.

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you on this.